# How to get the gpg key for a repository?

Tags: command-line, repository, add-apt-repository

When adding a repository through `add-apt-repository` a new `gpg` key will be add.

e,g:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:some-ppa
```

You will be asked to press Enter to import the gpg key. I need to get the gpg key for `ppa:some-ppa` without executing `add-apt-repository`.

Is it possible to get the `gpg` key **before** adding the repository (before executing `add-apt-repository`) from command line?

Comment: What PPA are you adding?  Please be specific.

Comment: @Terrance I have edited my question.

Comment: You will find the keys usually on the PPA itself under the Technical Details.  Example:  https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @Terrance Is there a way to get the gpg key from command line?

Comment: You can do either `gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --search <key>` or `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --search <key>` where sometimes you can find it by name or the most accurate is by key (last 8 digits).

Comment: @Terrance can you provide an example for "<key>" ?

Comment: Surely you can just stick `-y` on the command to install it automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a procedure that essentially tries to replicate `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:owner/name` but lets you do all the steps (including downloading the GPG key) manually:

1. Go to the page of the `owner/name` PPA on Launchpad: `https://launchpad.net/~owner/+archive/ubuntu/name`.
2. Look for signing key's fingerprint on the page.

   In the page there should be a section "Fingerprint:" with the key fingerprint printed below.
3. Download the PPA key into a specific directory on your system.

   - Download the key via the URL `https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x<fingerprint>`, where `<fingerprint>` is the value you found in step 2.
   - Dearmor the key and put it in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/owner_ubuntu_name.gpg`.
4. Create a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/owner-ubuntu-name.list` with these contents:

   ```
   deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/owner/name/ubuntu <codename> main
   ```

   where `<codename>` is what `lsb_release -sc` gives.
5. Enjoy the new software that the PPA provides!

### Example, Safe Eyes (`ppa:slgobinath/safeeyes`) software

1. Go to [https://launchpad.net/~slgobinath/+archive/ubuntu/safeeyes](https://launchpad.net/%7Eslgobinath/+archive/ubuntu/safeeyes)
2. As of 7th March 2023 the page says:

   > Fingerprint:
   >
   > 53A5446DABC1B038506E33F5E71C080343BB5214
3. Run:

   ```bash
   curl -S "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x53A5446DABC1B038506E33F5E71C080343BB5214" \
     | sudo gpg --batch --yes --dearmor --output "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/slgobinath_ubuntu_safeeyes.gpg"
   ```
4. Run:

   ```bash
   echo "deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/slgobinath/safeeyes/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" \
     | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/slgobinath-ubuntu-safeeyes.list
   ```
5. Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install safeeyes` and enjoy your new software!

Comment: It seems at least on Ubuntu 22.04 you can skip the dearmor step, if you save the keyserver's response to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/somename.asc` (note the `.asc` extension)