# gpg: My PPA setup is causing DEPRECATION Warning, Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, gnupg

My PPA setup is causing DEPRECATION Warning:

`W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/myid/ppa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.`

and

I know superficially it can be fixed with
[apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system)

But my question is how to setup my PPA source so that it is not causing such DEPRECATION Warning in the first place.

The answer in [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398344/apt-key-deprecation-warning-when-updating-system) still uses `apt-key`:

`sudo apt-key export 91E7EE5E | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/team-xbmc.gpg`

which gives the Warning of:

`Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).`

**How can I prepare my PPA repo keys directly from a keyserver** instead going through `apt-key`?

I tried

`gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 91E7EE5E --dearmour -o /tmp/ppa.gpg`

But it only imported to my own `~/.gnupg/pubring.kbx` file, instead of writing to /tmp/ppa.gpg.

`gpg --export --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 91E7EE5E | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /tmp/ppa.gpg`

is not doing what I want either.

And finally, how can I verify the final `/tmp/ppa.gpg` file, hopefully to get an output just like:

```
pub   rsa4096 2017-05-08 [SCEA]
      1EDD E2CD FC02 5D17 F6DA  9EC0 ADAE 6AD2 8A8F 901A
uid           [ unknown] Sublime HQ Pty Ltd <support@sublimetext.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-05-08 [S]
```

Comment: Found the answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1458126/843820